# A good CTA for Augmented Reality function?

Tags: mobile-application, call-to-action, augmented-reality, cta

I am designing a consumer app for enhancing a museum visit. At the entrance users can use the Augmented Reality functionality to frame the exhibition poster and see a video overlay. How do you design a call to action in the homepage to drive users to use the AR function?

I attached a mockup of the homepage:

[image: app homepage mockup]

Comment: Put QR codes on the poster. Drives users to the AR function with the benefit of telling the app which poster the user is at.

Comment: Marco, does this have some additional cost for the user? If not, why don't you simply offer the AR version alone and make everyone happy?

Comment: What does *Start the experience* do?

Comment: @Devin the AR is an add-on function. It is there "just for fun", while the core function is the Guide experience

Comment: @AndreDickson "Start the experience" is the main function, it is an interactive guide for the museum

Comment: Seems like a good opportunity to make a paper prototype, and try out your experience with some real users.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, one common way to demonstrate a virtual and real crossover capacity is barcodes. However that's not entirely without cost because you'll have to redo all the posters and wall art to include the barcodes, and they'll steal from or otherwise diminish the aesthetics of the posters.

Instead, digitised images (photos!) of the posters, with a strong priority given to the first poster they're likely to see on entrance, as buttons/windows to the AR experience, might be the best possible "clean" solution.

Sequence and weight these images of the posters as a well organised array of buttons with a simple scrolling mechanism and you might also wind up encouraging visitors to more deeply explore and discover the extent of the museum.

Comment: They do make QR/barcode stickers so if there's any blank space on the poster you can stick it to it instead of reprinting the whole thing, to save some money.

Comment: "or otherwise diminish the aesthetics of the posters"

Comment: I was more addressing the "you'll have to redo all the posters and wall art" which you have as an addition to diminishing the aesthetics. But this was just an added option for OP, either way I think this is the best route.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended that you only have one CTA per page. Your homepage has 3. So it will be understandable if the user doesn't do what you expect them to do at this stage.

I think you need to create a clear, guided experience for the user - that typically requires one CTA per screen.

If the AR function is to be used with the exhibition poster - you need to surface this option at the right time and ensure your provide enough instruction to the user. If you can't label this CTA to be self-explanatory provide some on screen text alongside it so that the user knows when they can use it. You don't want the user to miss the opportunity to use this feature.

Comment: I'm thinking about to use that "self explanatory text" as CTA: something like "frame the poster". But I am asking because am not totally sure

Comment: @MarcoTatta I see. For the labal you might want to try the benefit of performing the action rather than the action itself. I'm not clear on the benefit but something like "unlock the exhibition trailer" or "unlock the poster video". You can detail the instructions after the user clicks the CTA.